# Flutter store TextStyle in firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to store a `TextStyle` in `firestore` but i don't know how, this is the `TextStyle` that i stored in `firestore` as string but i don't know how to convert it from a `string` to `TextStyle` so i can apply it to a text widget:

```
GoogleFonts.lato(
    textStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14.0,
        color: Color(0xFFaaaaaa),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        height: 1.3,
    ),
);
```

I tried to store only the google font name like `lato` in the example above but i had the same problem, i don't know how to inject it into the `TextStyle` object.

The problem is the google font library has about 900 fonts, if they were just a few i could make a map that convert `id` to `TextStyle` then store those `ids` in `firestore`, but i the number of fonts are big.

Is there a way or a work around to make this work?

Comment: google font's will not work in release mode, you have to manually add font's.  https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya have you tried it? because they didn't say anything about that, they said the opposite of that, meaning you don't need to manually add font's, because they do that for you when the user open the app

Comment: read following section.  "Bundling font files in your application's assets" @ler

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya i didn't know that, thanks for pointing to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check this google font method?
simple use:

```
Text(
  'This is Google Fonts',
  style: GoogleFonts.getFont('Lato'),
),
```

advenced use:

```
Text(
  'This is Google Fonts',
   style: GoogleFonts.getFont(
    'Lato',
     fontSize: 14,
     color: Colors.red,
     textStyle: ...
   ),
);
```

Comment: the problem with this method is you can't add other things like `fontSize`, or `color` ....